# The following exception was thrown by the web event provider 'EventLogProvider'

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, asp.net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I can't get a new ASP.NET 4.0 application to work on IIS 7, in Windows 2008 R2. All I can see in my event log is the below error. I can't seem to find any information about what it means, can anybody help?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          11/27/2011 4:22:13 PM
Event ID:      1301
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      [myserver].[mydomain].com
Description:
The following exception was thrown by the web event provider 'EventLogProvider' in the application '/[myapp]' (in an application lifetime a maximum of one exception will be logged per provider instance):

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_AuthenticationType()
   at System.Web.Management.EventLogWebEventProvider.AddWebRequestInformationDataFields(ArrayList dataFields, WebRequestInformation reqInfo)
   at System.Web.Management.EventLogWebEventProvider.ProcessEvent(WebBaseEvent eventRaised)
   at System.Web.Management.WebBaseEvent.RaiseInternal(WebBaseEvent eventRaised, ArrayList firingRuleInfos, Int32 index0, Int32 index1)
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">1301</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-11-27T21:22:13.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1357</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>[myserver].[mydomain].com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>EventLogProvider</Data>
    <Data>/[MyApp]</Data>
    <Data>System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_AuthenticationType()
   at System.Web.Management.EventLogWebEventProvider.AddWebRequestInformationDataFields(ArrayList dataFields, WebRequestInformation reqInfo)
   at System.Web.Management.EventLogWebEventProvider.ProcessEvent(WebBaseEvent eventRaised)
   at System.Web.Management.WebBaseEvent.RaiseInternal(WebBaseEvent eventRaised, ArrayList firingRuleInfos, Int32 index0, Int32 index1)</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your code is attempting to write to the event log, but the user that the application pool is running as does not have this authority.

You will need to change the application pool to run as a different user or have your website impersonate a well-known user if you cannot change the app pool identity.

Comment: Thank you Competent_Tech. This was it exactly.

Comment: please do explain more....